# 04 Neon Srt4 1st gear problems

Tags: manual-transmission, dodge, shifting, neon

For some reason whenever I try to put my car into 1st gear it will grind, but if I put it in 2nd gear then into first gear quickly it won't grind. Anyone have a clue on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due to the first gear synchro failing - putting it into 2nd then first reduces the speed difference that the first gear synchro has to deal with.

This should be checked by a transmission specialist as they should be able to confirm the diagnisis.